# How to add incremental classes to an (Multiupload Filefield Widget) image field

Tags: views, files

I was hoping some one can help me to add class in to a field that is using the Multiupload (7.x.1.13), Multiupload Filefield Widget (7.x.13) as well as the Colorbox (7.x-2.5) module. I have a view which outputs the following markup:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a rel="gallery-node-15" class="colorbox init-colorbox-processed cboxElement" title="Dog" href="http://mysite.com/sites/default/files/styles/gallery_full_size/public/images/imagegallery/P1000388.JPG?itok=dCb-jJzT">
      <img width="70" height="70" title="Dog" alt="Image 1" src="http://mysite.com/sites/default/files/styles/mini_thumbnail/public/images/imagegallery/P1000388.JPG?itok=6fAcLEY-" typeof="foaf:Image">
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a rel="gallery-node-15" class="colorbox init-colorbox-processed cboxElement" title="" href="http://mysite.com/sites/default/files/styles/gallery_full_size/public/images/imagegallery/P1000387.JPG?itok=pm9TDGJr">
           <img width="70" height="70" title="" alt="Image 2" src="http://mysite.com/sites/default/files/styles/mini_thumbnail/public/images/imagegallery/P1000387.JPG?itok=Jojtr1Ht" typeof="foaf:Image">
      </a>
  </li>
```

I was trying to be able to add classes into the img tag and to do it using a loop so that you end up with myclass1, myclass2...myclass6...

However, there seems to be an issue with Views and Multiupload as Views Style Settings also appear to be disabled. By that I mean if you try to for example check the "Customize field HTML" check box, the settings are not saved. The same is true for the other style setting options.

I apologise for my original post, nooby mistake, please forgive me.

Comment: What do you mean by incremental classes? Remember that questions about *"Implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided"* are [not welcome here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Yours is bit better than that, but it is still unclear without following that link. And can you guarantee this link will be still valid in a year? Two? Five? We answer not for you. We answer for the whole community, so it is important to ask in a way that will let your question be useful in the future.

Comment: Also, seems that [with CSS3 you don't need it at all](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).